# How to loop in a folder with batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, xcopy

I need to do something with a batch file....

I need to copy a folder to another folder but...

If the new folder exist, I need to verify if the file in new folder exist, then I need to rename the file with «.old» at the end of this file before to copy the new file. 
I have a great experience of programming in Java, php etc, but not really with batch file...

I m using a syntax of java/php to explain my problem....

```
set folderOrigin=d:\test1
set folderFinal=d:\test5 
if EXIST %folderFinal% (
  for (fileOrigin : folderOrigin){
      variableNamefileOrigin = fileOrigin
      for (fileFinal : folderFinal){
          variableNamefileFinal = fileFinal            
          if (variableNamefileOrigin == variableNamefileFinal){
              newvariable = variableNamefileFinal + ".old"
              ren variableNamefileFinal newvariable
              xcopy /s /q %folderOrigin%+%variableNamefileOrigin% 
              %folderFinal%+%variableNamefileFinal% 
          }
      }
  }
) else (
    xcopy /s /q %dossierOrigine% %dossierDestinataire%
)
pause
```

Thx everyone !

Comment: What help file did you read that said you can use curly braces? You are not using the correct syntax with the majority of your commands. Open up a command prompt and type the command name followed by a /? to read the help file for the command.

Comment: @Squashman Perhaps the line `I m using a syntax of java/php to explain my problem....` may explain the braces heresy

Comment: @Magoo good point. Still not an excuse for not reading the help file to determine the correct syntax.

Comment: I used this syntax as a pseudo-code to explain my problem...

I know the help...i already read a little bit about it....but it not easy to understand...:)

PS : My English is not perfect, so I try to write something clear to explain my problem

Comment: So you want us to write a script for you based on your pseudo-code? This is not the right place for such requests! You have to try it on your own and return when you have a specific problem! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: It's ok guys, i will try my myself, but i saw one answer finaly, i wil lcheck that very soon....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the source directory ("folders" are artifacts in the GUI; the structures in the filesystem are "directories") is `%sourceFolder%` and the destination directory is `%finalFolder%`; and also assuming that you need to copy only *files* (not an entire subtree):

1. To loop through the files in `%sourceFolder%` you use a `for` loop:

   ```
   for %%f in ("%sourceFolder%\*") do call :copyOneFile "%%~f"
   exit /b
   ```
2. In the subroutine `:copyOneFile` you have the current file as `%1`. To check whether it exists in `%finalFolder%` you use `if exist`, and if so you rename it, but not before checking if the `.old` file exists already:

   ```
   :copyOneFile

   if exist "%finalFolder%\%~nx1" (
     if exist "%finalFolder\%~n1.old" del "%finalFolder\%~n1.old"
     ren "%finalFolder\%~nx1" "%~n1.old"
   )
   ```
3. Now you can copy the file from the source folder to the destination folder:

   ```
   copy "%~1" "%finalFolder%
   ```

To understand the constructions `%~nx1` and so on, use `for /?`. Note than the second argument of `ren` must have only the filename, a path is not allowed.

If you need to copy an entire subtree then:

- After copying the files, redo with `for /d` to get directories.
- Use the appropriate commands instead of `del` and `copy`.